# BootStrapDialog + AngularJS filters - the filter is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using bootstrap dialog and i like it very much. Code below.

```
function resolveTicket(itemId) {
    //return dataservice.remedy.resolveTicket(itemId, 'test').then(function (data) {
    //    log('Resolved tkt ' + itemId + ' by ' + config.user);
    //});
    var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
        title: 'Resolve ' + itemId,
        message: '<textarea id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" rows="5" cols="71"></textarea>',
        draggable: true,
        buttons: [{
            label: 'Resolve',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: function (dialogref) {
                dialogref.close();
                var closureComments = dialogref.getModalBody().find('textarea').val();
                return dataservice.remedy.resolveTicket(itemId, closureComments).then(function (data) {
                    log('Resolved tkt ' + itemId + ' by ' + config.user);
                });
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Close',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: function (dialogItself) {
                dialogItself.close();
            }
        }]
    });
    dialog.realize();
    dialog.getModalHeader().css('background-color', 'rgb(44, 62, 80)');
    dialog.open();
}

<ul class="list-unstyled item-list">
    <li ng-repeat="r in vm.remedyTickets  | orderBy:'CreatedDate' ">
        <span class="item rt">
            <!--Row 1-->
            <div class="itemRow">
                <div class="r1l">
                    <span>{{r.FullName}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Row 2-->
            <div class="itemRow">
                <div class="r1l">
                    <span class="ticketNumText">{{r.TaskId}}</span>
                    <a class="btn btn-xs disabled ticket-{{r.StatusId}}">{{r.StatusId}}</a>
                </div>
                <div class=" r1r quickActions">
                    <span class="small glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Resolve/Close the ticket" data-ng-click="vm.resolveTicket(r.TaskId);$event.stopPropagation();"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
           </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The Resolve button resolves the ticket and updates the status as 'Resolved'. Works good so far.

Today i introduced a filter in ng-repeat like below.

```
<li ng-repeat="r in vm.remedyTickets  | orderBy:'CreatedDate' | filter: { StatusId: '!Resolved'} ">
```

My expectation was, as soon as i resolve the ticket(by opening the dialog and clicking on resolve button), the status should change to Resolved and the ticket should go away from the ng-repeat.

This is not working if i put the resolve ticket inside bootstrap dialog like above. The ticket is resolved, status is updated as 'Resolved' but it is still in the ng-repeat.

If i change the javascript like below, it works i.e., as soon as i resolve the ticket, it goes away.

```
function resolveTicket(itemId) {
    return dataservice.remedy.resolveTicket(itemId, 'test').then(function (data) {
        log('Resolved tkt ' + itemId + ' by ' + config.user);
    });
}
```

Problem is with BootStrapDialog + angularjs filters

Any idea/alternative?